# Possible way to attach database to exe

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I created a small application using C# winforms that uses SQL Server as a database.

Is there a way to attach the database to the exe file so I won't need to install SQL Server on all the machines that I want to run the program on?

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know, that's where [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) comes into play.

Quoting [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact):

> Unlike other editions of Microsoft SQL Server, SQL CE runs in-process with the application which is hosting it; while having a memory footprint of less than 2 MB;

Answer (score 6):

in addition to sql server compact, there is also a [c# port of sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) that you could use.

Comment: Speaking of SQLite, there is also a fairly feature-complete ADO.NET 2.0/3.5 provider for SQLite (namespace `System.Data.SQLite`) at http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/.

Comment: I second System.Data.Sqlite. All you need to do is include a dll in your installer. The database exists in a single file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx)?

It's a Zero-config, single file version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Server compact:
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx

or SQLite:
http://www.sqlite.org/
- it has a .NET library that you can download and use...it's pretty fast and compact

Answer (score 1):

You can included it as part of the app installer.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562%28SQL.90%29.aspx) article